# How to get an action from different controller in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Consider I am in `application_controller_spec.rb`. In this file, I need to call the index action of `users_controller.rb` as `get :index`, but this does not work:

```
get :index :controller :user_controller
get 'UsersController#index'
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you're trying to test in this spec? And why you need to particularly call an action from the users controller? That would help us in solving this more effectively.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use controller spec as a feature spec. Don't. Write a proper feature spec instead.